# How to avoid focusing on next element on TAB key press after scrollIntoView on page-load in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, angular, google-chrome, js-scrollintoview

I am facing this weird issue on Chrome browser only. I am using `scrollIntoView` method just after page load (ngAfterViewInit of angular component).
So, when the page is loaded and it scroll's to element, everything is fine. Now, when I press the TAB key, the focus starts from the next element of the scrollIntoView'ed element on Chrome. On other browsers, the focus starts form the first element of the DOM.

Is there a way so that the focus should start from first element of DOM even after using scrollIntoView on page-load

Issue could be reproduced here - https://scrollintoview-issue.stackblitz.io/

- Open the link in Chrome and then press TAB
- Open it in Firefox or Edge and press TAB
- Notice the difference about from where the focus starts

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    const eleToScroll = this._el.nativeElement.querySelector('#checking1');
    eleToScroll.scrollIntoView();
  }
```

Expected - on Chrome, the focus should not start from next element of the scrollIntoView'ed element. It should start for the first element in the DOM

Actual - the focus is starting from the next element of the scrollIntoView'ed element on page load.

Comment: What about [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex). ?

Comment: @JaydeepMor : I don't think it has to do anything with tabindex. I am using anchor tags which are by default focusable.

Answer (score 0):

`scrollIntoView` is described as "[an experimental feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51958275/1005607)." It affects tab order. The safe way to scroll is by getting `getClientBoundingRect` and doing `window.scrollTo` as follows:

```
var element = document.getElementById("elementId");
var y = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY - 15; // e.g. with extra offset
window.scrollTo(0, y);
```

This will not affect tab order.